# PHP - replace text without overwriting already replaced text

Tags: php, replace

I want to replace specific characters in string without replacing them again. Here is what I am talking about:

```
// Outputs F because A is replaced with B, then B is replaced with C, and so on...
// Finally E is replaced with F, because of left to right replacements.
$search  = array('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E');
$replace = array('B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F');
$subject = 'A';
echo str_replace($search, $replace, $subject);

// Outputs: apearpearle pear
// For the same reason mentioned above
$letters = array('a', 'p');
$fruit   = array('apple', 'pear');
$text    = 'a p';
$output  = str_replace($letters, $fruit, $text);
echo $output;
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: [`strtr`](http://php.net/strtr)

Comment: First replace them with some characters which are not in the text. Later replace them it to what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample Code to replace text using `strtr` function as suggested by @NiettheDarkAbsol

```
<?php 

$replacepair  = array('A' => 'B', 'B' =>'C', 'C'=>'D', 'D'=>'E', 'E'=> 'F');
$subject = 'A';

echo strtr($subject, $replacepair); // outputs B
```

Answer (score 0):

First replace them with some characters which are not in the text. Later replace them it to what you want.

```
$letters = array('a', 'p');
$fruit   = array('*', '#');
$text    = 'a p';
$output  = str_replace($letters, $fruit, $text);

$letters = array('*', '#');
$fruit   = array('apple', 'pear');
$output  = str_replace($letters, $fruit, $output);
echo $output;
```